# Pandas dataframe how to add column of distance from previous row?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-science, data-munging

I have a dataframe of locations:

```
df = X    Y 
     1    1
     2    1
     2    1 
     2    2
     3    3
     5    5    
    5.5   5.5
```

I want to add a columns, with the distance to the previous point:
So it will be:

```
df = X    Y    Distance
     1    1     0
     2    1     1
     2    1     0
     2    2     1
     3    3     2
     5    5     2
    5.5   5.5   1
```

What is the best way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [pd.Series.diff](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) method.

For instance, to compute the eulerian distance, using also [np.sqrt](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sqrt.html), you would do like this:

```
import numpy as np
df["Distance"] = np.sqrt(df.X.diff()**2 + df.Y.diff()**2)
```